# Position of a particle, Newtons Second Law

Tags: calculus, physics

A particle of mass $40$ kg moves in a straight line such that the force (in newtons) acting on it at time $t$ (in seconds) is given by $$160t^4-320t^2-360$$ If at time $t=0$ its velocity $v$ is given by $v(0)=10$, and its position $x$ (in m) is given by $x(0)=14$, what is the position of the particle at time $t$?

I have that by Newton's second Law $$F=m\cdot a=40\cdot\frac{dv}{dt}=160t^4-320t^2-360\to\frac{dv}{dt}=4t^4-8t^2-9\\
v(t)=\frac{4}{5}t^5-\frac{8}{3}t^3-9t+v_0$$

$v(0)=v_0=10$.

What do I need to substitute in and where to get the final answer?

Comment: $v(t)=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$. 

Should help!

Comment: You currently only have an equation for velocity. You now need to integrate your equation for velocity to get an equation that expresses the position of the particle as a function of time.

Comment: So do I need to integrate v(t) giving $$2t^6/15 -2t^4/3 -9t^2/2$$?

Comment: You are solving the following differential equation: 
\begin{align}
\ddot x &= \frac 1m F \\
\dot x(0) &= v_0\\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{align}
So you should expect to integrate twice if you want to get back $x$.

Comment: I don't *think* this is in (arithmetic-dynamics), but am not sure enough to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you know the velocity, you can use:

$v(t)=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$

So you compute the particle's position at time t: $x(t)$.

$x(t)=\dfrac{2}{15}t^6−\dfrac{2}{3}t^4−\dfrac{9}{2}t^2+10t+C$, where C is a constante.

Boundary condition:

$\begin{align}
x(0) &= C\\
 &=14
\end{align}$

Thus: $x(t)=\dfrac{2}{15}t^6−\dfrac{2}{3}t^4−\dfrac{9}{2}t^2+10t+14$

Note also: $a(t)=\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is the acceleration of the particule at time t.